# PyQt5 Set TextBrowser Scrollbar Color

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I got a textbrowser in PyQt and I want to change the color of the scrollbar next to the textbrowser, but i dont know how to do that. My current textbrowser looks like that:

[image: HERE]

Because it's white on white it looks very bad, that's why i want to change the color.

Comment: How are you setting the background color of the text-browser?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: that's the default look of the textbrowser, i want to change the scrollbar color to gray

Comment: In the standard styles available on Windows 10 at least, the default background color of a scroll bar is grey, so I suspect that you have set a stylesheet of either the text browser itself or any of its parents that changes the background color, but that's only conjecture without seeing your code.

Comment: I cannot test with the default windowsvista style, but I'd try setting the color on one of the palette roles (probably Base or Window) and then set the palette on the scroll bar only (not the QTextBrowser), but I'm not sure about that either, as both windows and macos styles rely on the system api to draw some elements